Can't get div element with Children.toArray()
I'm having a problem getting children of children. I need to get the first div element inside another first div but the 2nd Children.toArray(..)[0] doesn't work, it gets the same outer div. I suspect it could be because children is on components but not for divs.
This renders the entire inner div with the divs for "results" and "filters". How can I get each of the nested inner divs so I can do something like this:
Children.forEach(navElements, child => navLinks.push(<a href="#" someSetStateFunction={..}>{child}</a>));

I'm new to React and haven't been able to find much on using the component children property.
function renderNavigation() {
    const navElements = Children.toArray(children)[0];
    return Children.toArray(navElements)[0];;
}


<Sidebar>
  <ViewSwitch>
    <div style={{backgroundColor: "blue", color: "white"}}>
      <div>results</div>
      <div>filters</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ResultList></ResultList>
      <Filters></Filters>
    </div>
  </ViewSwitch>


Children is a legacy API and using it is generally discouraged, why do you need to do this?

@DBS Was going to make a component that hides/shows components with tabs but since it is a legacy API and discouraged I guess I won't be doing it like this.

Children.toArray()  flattens the children nested structure and returns a single-level array.
This behaviour is clearly defined in the documentation.

Returns a flat array of elements in children.

